# i want data with where condition of date field - compare two dates discarding time part

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my query :

```
SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], 
USERINFO.NAME [Name] FROM USERINFO where CHECKTIME='2014-09-08'
```

when i write above query then it will not return the value of checktime='2014-09-08'

```
but when i write checktime>='2014-09-08' then it will give 
me the output of 2014-09-08 and 2014-09-09
```

but i want only output of `checktime='2014-09-08`

my checktime filed contain below data:

```
checktime
2014-09-08 09:19:34.000
2014-09-08 11:19:34.000
2014-09-09 09:19:34.000
2014-09-09 10:19:34.000
```

so how can i get only output of checktime='2014-09-08' ?

Comment: is field of type varchar() or datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is having equality between a field that may contain a value like `2014-09-08 09:19:34.000` and a value that is `2014-09-08`. These are in no way equal. Having no time is equevalent to the midnight of the specified date, so `2014-09-08` is equal to `2014-09-08 00:00:00.000`.

You need a way to strip the time portion from your datetime field.

```
SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], 
       USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], 
       USERINFO.NAME [Name] 
FROM USERINFO 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CHECKTIME,112))='2014-09-08'
```

I think that in SQL Server 2008R2(could work in 2008) and above you could use:

```
SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], 
       USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], 
       USERINFO.NAME [Name] 
FROM USERINFO 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,CHECKTIME)='2014-09-08'
```

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dae7f/1)** showing both cases.

The above cases will convert the field in the table, so you may want to avoid that using `>=` and `<` as a performance boost to your query. You may write a bit more, but you will do it only once, though the SQL will convert each time you run this. So maybe a solution as the one below may be more appropriate:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DateTo AS DATETIME
SET @DateFrom = '20140908'
SET @DateTo = DATEADD(day,1,@DateFrom)

SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], 
       USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], 
       USERINFO.NAME [Name] 
FROM   USERINFO 
WHERE  CHECKTIME >= @DateFrom
       AND CHECKTIME < @DateTo
```

Comment: @deepak Anytime. You might want to consider my third option though.

Comment: @deepak I know it does. But in the long run and if you ever end up trying to fine tune performance, you may need the last option. I usually use the 1st one myself anyway :-)

Comment: ok will keep this in my mind about the last solutions and will use it... Thank you for your time.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you are comparing unequal values. Here , you are comaparing **2014-09-08** **09:19:34.000** with some thing line **2014-09-08 00:00:00.000**

So that is the reasoon , when equality operator is used , it is not returning any thing.

So, you need to discard the time part from the date time. This is can be done as follows:

```
SELECT USERINFO.USERID [User ID], USERINFO.BADGENUMBER [Employee No],USERINFO.NAME [Name] 
FROM USERINFO 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CHECKTIME,112))='2014-09-08'
```

You need to specify an option while converting to varchar(). You can refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a date-time value in your DB, and the time part is different from "00:00".

What you have to do is to get rid of the time part of the db value, so that you can compare it with the provided date.

There is no direct way to do it, but you can:

- convert both dates to a text format which only includes the yyyy-mm-dd part [CAST AND CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- use a function to extract the y, m, d parts of the date and compare them [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)
- convert both dates to integer, and compare the values (SQL server stores the date in a floating point number format, where the integer part is the number of days since a reference date, and the decimal part represents the hh:mm:ss, etc.) [CAST AND CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- verify that the DB data is >= than the provided date, and < than the provided data plus one day, calculated with [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)